# setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs gives error in real device

Tags: java, android

when a set :

browser.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

it works fine in the android emulator, but when i want to tested it in my real android device  it gives an error in that line . do i need to change something in my phone settings ??

Comment: Examine LogCat to see the Java stack trace associated with your error.

Comment: the logcat shows : 
`code fatal exception : main
java.lang.nosuchMethodError: android.webkit.Websettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs`

Every thing works fine in the android emulator, but in my phone it gives me this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your phone apparently is not running Android 4.2 or higher. [`setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs()` is only available on API Level 16+](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs%28boolean%29).

Hence, wrap the call in an `if` block to only call it on API Level 16+:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
  yourWebView.getWebSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(whateverValueYouAreUsing);
}
```

Comment: and what should i do ?

Comment: @neustre: Not call it on older devices. `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) { // do your work }`

Comment: @neustre: How should I know? I am not writing your app. Any time you want to reference classes or methods only on certain Android API levels, use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to find out what API level is on the current device.

Comment: because I'm building a hybrid android app , the only servlet i have is the one where i call the webview with all the settings ... so i must put that code int that servlet ..? but where exactly after the setAllowuniversal ...?

Comment: Jelly bean mr1 is api 17. The setting is available on 16 which is 4.1 Jelly bean.